# Selecting rows based on data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn how to relate data in one table to another table.

Lets say I have a table called 'car ids' that contains nothing but ids for the cars stored in a separate table. This 'separate' table is called 'cars' and contains the car id AND make and model.

I am trying to come up with a mysql statement that selects the row from the car table by relating the id from the car id table to the car table.

Something like:

mysql_select("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id=["SELECT id FROM car_id"]");

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you would have a table of just car id's and then a table with the information about those cars, but here is the sort of query you would need

```
SELECT cars.* FROM cars JOIN ids on cars.id = ids.car_id
```

The key is using JOINs

Comment: haha it was hard for me to come up with an example... trust me, I don't have a table of just car id's ;) thank you! this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * FROM cars,ids where cars.id=ids.id and ids.id={something}
```

where {something} is some condition for id

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT cars.*, cars_id.*
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN cars_id
ON cars_id.id = cars.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

```
SELECT * FROM cars INNER JOIN car_id on cars.id=car_id.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `JOIN`. For your example, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cars` C
JOIN `ids` I ON C.id=C.car_id
```

Note that there are a lot of different ways to join two tables; you're going to need to either specify what you need better, or start reading up on joins.